# Location of built in functions Microchip C30 Compiler

Tags: c, compiler-construction, microcontroller, built-in, microchip

I am asking this just out of curiosity.

I am using Microchip C30 compiler to develop EEPROM driver code for PIC24F.
During this I used C30 builtin functions such as
__builtin_tblwtl(), __builtin_tbloffset etc.
How can I find the location of builtin functions? From Wiki I found this:

> "Some compilers (for example, GCC[7]) provide built-in versions of many
>   of the functions in the C standard library; that is, the
>   implementations of the functions are written into the compiled object
>   file, and the program calls the built-in versions instead of the
>   functions in the C library shared object file"

Does this mean that these functions are written inside the object files of compiler?So does that mean we cannot see it as a code?
I have searched the entire C30 directory and didn't find these functions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user defined functions only stored in objects file of the compiler and above mention functions `__builtin_tblwtl()`, `__builtin_tbloffset` etc are previously written in library of Microchip C30 compiler.So you only get link to that library. for example in linux `gcc` is compiler while `glibc` are the runtime libraries.